error connecting to node check browser console for details pterodactyl
I cannot turn on the Node server
/api/remote/servers?page=0&per_page=50": unsupported protocol scheme ""
http: request creation failed
enter image description here
systemctl restart wings
INFO: [May  7 09:06:52.066] loading configuration from file config_file=/etc/pterodactyl/config.yml
INFO: [May  7 09:06:52.066] configured wings with system timezone timezone=Etc/UTC
INFO: [May  7 09:06:52.066] checking for pterodactyl system user username=pterodactyl
INFO: [May  7 09:06:52.066] configured system user successfully gid=997 uid=997 username=pterodactyl
INFO: [May  7 09:06:52.068] fetching list of servers from API
FATAL: [May  7 09:07:19.665] failed to load server configurations error=http: request creation failed: Get "/api/remote/servers?page=0&per_page=50": unsupported protocol scheme ""
Stacktrace:

Can you please add more details?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
